# Richfaces datatable exception: java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm using JSF 2.1, Richfaces 4.2.2 and for below mentioned code I'm getting java.io.NotSerializableException: org.richfaces.component.SavedState exception.

Bean Scope: Session

Facelet code:

```
<rich:dataTable id="table" value="#{mapActivityGroup.addActivityGroupModelList}" 
      var="model">
    <rich:column>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox" value="#{model.selected}" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column filterValue="#{mapActivityGroup.categoryFilter}" 
                 filterExpression="#{fn:containsIgnoreCase(model.categoryName,
                 mapActivityGroup.categoryFilter)}" >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:outputText value="Category" />
                <h:inputText value="#{mapActivityGroup.categoryFilter}">
                    <a4j:ajax render="table" execute="@this" event="blur" />
                </h:inputText>
            </h:panelGroup> 
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{model.categoryName==null?'':model.categoryName}"/>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Exception:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.richfaces.component.SavedState
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1947.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
```

I have googled but couldn't found anything substantial. Does anyone has any idea why is it happening ?

Comment: It's not visible in the code posted so far, but the symptoms suggests that you're referencing an `UIComponent` as bean property. Is this true? You should not do that in view/session scoped beans with JSF2 partial state saving enabled, but only in request scoped beans as UI components are supposed to be created on a per-request basis.

Comment: No, I'm not using any `UIComponent` as bean property. However, when I removed `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` its working fine.

Comment: @BalusC I tried to change the bean scope to `request` but that didn't worked either.

Comment: This is just weird. Which JSF impl/version?

Comment: @BalusC Its JSF 2.0, I mistakenly mentioned it 2.1 earlier.

Comment: Okay, but that's just a spec version. I was asking the the implementation name and its version. E.g. "Mojarra 2.1.17".

Comment: @BalusC Mojarra 2.0.2-FCS

Comment: Whoops, that's almost 3 years old. Do you see chance to upgrade it to the latest? You can download it from http://javaserverfaces.java.net.

Comment: @BalusC Well, its too late to do that, will do that for next application. Thanks though !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web.xml I changed `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` to `server` and it worked.

Comment: That's the how, but that's not the *why* you were having the problem. A member variable of your backing bean is not serializable (does not implement `java.io.Serializable`) and as a result causes view serialization to fail. Mark the complex/pojo type member variables as `transient`

Comment: @kolossus While I was working over it I tried that by implementing `java.io.Serializable` for the backing bean however it didn't worked that way too.

Comment: It's not just your managed bean that needs to be serializable, the member variables and properties of the bean need to be serializable also